# Android how to know when the context menu is rendered completely

Tags: android, android-contextmenu

In Android, when a user wants to show a context menu, they need to do a long click on some controls. After that, the callback `onCreateContextMenu` is run to create a context menu on the screen. But are there any listeners to know when the context menu has been completely rendered?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {  
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Something");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Something else");  
}
```

Here the menu.add will return MenuItem and the last menu item will indicate that Context Menu is completely rendered.